# ASP.net C# blog

Tags: c#, asp.net, blogs, asp.net-3.5, webforms

I know this question has been asked many times for now but I am looking for a specific blogging software to add to my website, **already built using C# & ASP.net**.

What I want is a blog who will only allow the users logged in using the default ASP.net logging engine to comment and a user with the certain roles to write new posts.

I know that by googling this I get tons of answers, but I cannot seem to find one that integrates with the default **ASP.net login**.

P.S. I prefer it to be written in web forms. No MVC is required & I am using .net 3.5.

Answer (score 5):

You can go for `BlogEngine.NET`

below tutorial help you to setup the ASP.net membership

http://nyveldt.com/blog/post/blogenginenet-screencast-sql-membership-and-roles-providers.aspx

Comment: you can check it here http://hostingconnection.godaddy.com/Application/BlogEngineNET.aspx

Comment: It seems more complicated than I wanted, all i need is a single blog with comments on the main page

Comment: You can have single blog also in BlogEngine.net

Comment: Can it be under the master page that I already designed for other pages?